# DataSet не получает таблицу

Tags: c#, база-данных

Всем привет. Создал я консольное приложение, добавил в проект новую БД, на БД нажал правой кнопкой и выбрал в меню пункт `Новый запрос`, и выполнил вот такой вот код

```
CREATE TABLE City
(
  id   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name CHAR(40)
)

CREATE TABLE Street
(
  id      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name    CHAR(40),
  id_city INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES City(id)
)
```

В БД создались две таблицы, далее я скопировал строку подключения в свой код и попробовал создать в таблице новую строку с помощью метода `NewRow()`, однако выскакивает эксепшн, что якобы нулевая ссылка. Почему так происходит ??  VS 2013update5 Ult. 
ПС. Вначале я подумал, что где-то названия попутал, однако все перепроверил - там все было правильным. Если вместо названия таблицы использовать ее индекс, тогда все работает. Почему так получается ?? Мой код ниже

```
static void Main()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\sergey\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [Street]", connection);
        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(data);
        DataRow dr = data.Tables["Street"].NewRow();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При заполнении `data` необходимо указать название таблицы как показано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699983/datasets-with-actual-tablename):

```
adapter.Fill(data, "Street");
```

Comment: Да, и правда. Спасибо. Я думал, что название автоматически берется.